# Какой алгоритм действий для ситуаций, в случае самоустранения модераторов?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, выборы

Сейчас 5 модераторов. Предположим, троим из них надоело нести бремя власти. Остаётся два модератора, но этого мало.

Что будет происходить в такой ситуации: снова выборы на несколько дней или есть более быстрый способ пробраться кому-то наверх в таких случаях?

Comment: Прочитал вопрос и на всякий случай проверил заперта ли дверь

Comment: решили как-то в обход выборов в модераторы пробраться? :-D

Comment: @mymedia, путь давно уже известен :-)

Comment: 3 модератора вполне справлялись 2 года. Чуть больше 2 модераторов (говорят, Бармалей был весьма неактивен) вполне справлялись пока шла бета. Одновременный уход трёх модераторов - весьма маловреноятная ситуация. Думаю, в любом случае месяц на выборы можно будет найти.

Comment: @Qwertiy моловреноятная ситуация возникновения пары ошибок в одном слове тем не менее имела место быть.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб тук-тук. — кто там? — это я, Grundy, пришел за вашим ♦

Comment: @alexolut, ага, смотришь его IP, а оно с твоим совпадает...

Comment: @mymedia обычное тестирование системы скорее, на случай незапланированных входных данных.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Не дождётесь!

(с) Рабинович из анекдота.

---

Кроме шуток — не беспокойтесь, система выдержит нагрузку достаточное время, чтобы можно было вернуть старых модераторов или набрать новых.

Тревог и других ситуаций, которые модератор должен обработать обязательно и срочно, не так уж много. Два модератора справятся с потоком наиболее важных тревог и даже продержат второстепенные достаточно долго, чтобы можно было выбрать новых модераторов.

Comment: Отметил тревогой "Не является ответом!", проверим беспристрастность)

Comment: @edem, поддержал. Но ответ, чьорт побьери, хорош!

Comment: @Other, edem, проверил тревоги, ничего крамольного в ответе не нашёл) Насколько я понял ответ, он про то, что просто запустят новые выборы в обычном порядке.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб проверять надо было на момент флаганья. Но кто-то, видимо, ещё не отошёл от эйфории ромба :)

Comment: @alexolut, наверное, вы правы)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, что было в тексте флагнутого? То, что сейчас или на момент флага (да, они разные)?

Comment: @alexolut тут сложная ситуация. После правки ответ стал ответом, но ваши тревоги остались — теперь они некорректны. Думаю, это нужно решать программно, то есть менять логику сайта. Или просто ждать, пока очередь протухнет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin почему нельзя отметить их как полезные?

Comment: @alexolut насколько я помню, дух поставит минус. Это ладно на Мете, а на основном сайте?

Comment: @alexolut кстати, меня бесит, что любая правка подтверждает эту тревогу и тогда дух тоже ставит минус. Уже обсуждалось не раз, все фичебагореквесты так и висят.

Answer (score 4):

По большому счету сайт достаточно хорошо модерируется из без явных действий со стороны ромбоносных товарищей. То есть вопросы могут как закрываться, так и переоткрываться, удаляться и восстанавливаться обычными участниками с необходимой репутацией; всякий спам и оскорбления удаляются при достаточном количестве тревог соответствующего типа на них как в сообщениях, так и в комментариях, очереди разгребаются.

Конечно, возможности модератора больше и достаточно его одного голоса, чтобы выполнить упомянутые выше действия, то есть с модераторами должно получаться быстрее обслуживать сайт.

Безусловно, некоторые действия, такие как удаление учетных записей, блокировка участников, обработка тревог, требующих явной обработки модератором, не будет выполнена, но с этим можно жить.

Таким образом, даже если все модераторы сайта разом [попадут под автобус](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0), сайт будет жить. А Николас (благо, что он не модератор) назначит новые выборы или вручную временных модераторов (как это было во время беты, емнип), например, из списка тех, кто занял третье, четвертое и т.д. места на прошедших недавно выборах.

Comment: `объединение учетных записей` недоступно модераторам, в двадцатый раз повторяю ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin тогда я вообще не понимаю, зачем нужны модераторы. :)

Comment: как же, для произвола. :)

Comment: _например, из списка тех, кто занял третье, четвертое и т.д. места на прошедших недавно выборах_ Не обращайте внимания на то, что я зловеще потираю руки!

Answer (score 4):

Назначение модератора - дело времени отлова Николаса (без спецназа только ждать появления, с ним - час-два) и назначение им роли для юзера (пять минут).

В чрезвычайной ситуации так и будет, но это крайне маловероятно.

Да и без модераторов мы продержимся до окончания выборов силами высокореповых пользователей и Николаса.

Answer (score 0):

Назначение временного модератора и переизбрание модератора.Только как я понял причины должны быть весомые, смерть, болезнь и уход от должности. Плюс срок надо назначить.

Comment: Уйти с поста можно только посмертно! :)